# map array with different object key

Tags: javascript

This is my output, what I want is something that I can map with `.map()` at the moment I'm not able to map it because there are login and `home_page` as key

```json
{
    "login": [
        {
            "id": "clgtg0inx0005sy0llfq2gkvp",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z"
        }
    ],
    "home_page": [
        {
            "id": "clgtewvcw0003sy0lps4i694l",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "clgtewood0001sy0lgevccham",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z"
        }
    ]
    "event_3": [{...}],
    "event_4": [{...}],
    ...
}
```

Results:

```
<ul>
 <li>login
  <ul>
   <li>login-info1</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>home_page
  <ul>
   <li>home_page-ino1</li>
   <li>home_page-ino2</li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

where I can expand and see details with below sub array

Let me explain better what i want is an array with a long list of events, and map these inside a UI, but as you can see as key I have the name of the events and the default .map() give me an error events.map is not a function. I need something that I can use to map correctly.

What I did

```js
const reGroup = (list, key) => {
const newGroup = {};
 list.forEach(item => {
  const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
  delete newItem[key];
  newGroup[item[key]] = newGroup[item[key]] || [];
  newGroup[item[key]].push(newItem);
 });
 return newGroup;
};

console.log(reGroup(res.data, 'name'));
setEvents(reGroup(res.data, 'name'))
```

and

```
{events?.map((d, i) => {
 return <li key={i} className="df-row gap-l">
  <InfoInput>{moment(new Date(d.createdAt)).format('MMM D, YYYY hh:mm a')}</InfoInput>
  {d.name}
 </li>
})}
```

Comment: check out [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: *"What I did ..."* wait, so you took a flat list `res.data`, grouped it by `name` and are now complaining that it is not longer a flat list but a dictionary where the items are grouped by what used to be the `name`? why? That's like slashing your own tires and then complaining how hard it is to drive with flats.

Comment: You are right, my “problem” is that with res.data I’m able to map the array, after grouped by name I’m no longer able to map it, but I need the array grouped not listed object by object

Comment: Did you take a look at Object.keys() and Object.entries()?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to merge the object?

```js
const data = {
    "login": [
        {
            "id": "clgtg0inx0005sy0llfq2gkvp",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z"
        }
    ],
    "home_page": [
        {
            "id": "clgtewvcw0003sy0lps4i694l",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "clgtewood0001sy0lgevccham",
            "user_id": "00004",
            "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
            "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z"
        }
    ]
}

const newData = [...data.login, ...data.home_page]

newData.map(item => console.log(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leverage the rest operator to get what you want.

Let's call your data object is `source`.

Your result object should be `const events = [...source.login, ...source.home_page]`

Comment: I need a way to map objects inside an array always grupped by object key (e.g. login, home_page and other events) @thelonglqd

Answer (score 0):

`[].concat(...Object.values(data))` or `Object.values(data).flat()` (as Thomas has mentioned below) can be used to output a 1D array that contains all the objects in the original object, regardless of which property they were nested under.

```js
const data = {
  "login": [
    {
      "id": "clgtg0inx0005sy0llfq2gkvp",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T13:26:20.541Z"
    }
  ],
  "home_page": [
    {
      "id": "clgtewvcw0003sy0lps4i694l",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:30.753Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "clgtewood0001sy0lgevccham",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T12:55:22.093Z"
    }
  ],
  "event_3": [
    {
      "id": "event_3_1",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T14:00:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T14:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "event_3_2",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T14:10:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T14:10:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "event_4": [
    {
      "id": "event_4_1",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T15:00:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T15:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "event_4_2",
      "user_id": "00004",
      "project_id": "clgqnhw9u0001syh9rbuvvpkv",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-23T15:10:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-04-23T15:10:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
};

const array = [].concat(...Object.values(data));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: `Object.values(data).flat()` see [Array#flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: I forgot about flat(). Thanks @Thomas